# How to extract multiwords in R?

Tags: r, text, stringr

I want to extract certain words positioned between years and the following comma in a given text. **The year may or may not have opening & closing parentheses**. Note that the year `1998` has no opening & closing parentheses whereas `(2020)` and `(2015)` have.

```
library(stringr)
txt <- "Mining exercise (2020) Mining, p. 628; Computer Science text 1998 Computer Science, p.345-355; Data mining (2015) J. Data Science, pp. 31-33"
comp <- c("Mining", "Computer Science", "J. Data Science")
pattern <- str_c(comp,collapse ="|")
```

`str_extract_all(txt, str_c("(?<=\\(\\d{4}\\)\\s)(", pattern, ")(?=,)"))[[1]]` gives me:

```
#  "Mining"          "J. Data Science"
```

But the answer should be:

```
# "Mining"  "Computer Science"  "J. Data Science"
```

by taking into account the **absence** of opening & closing parentheses around `1998`. Any help, please?

Comment: Try `unlist(str_extract_all(txt, str_c("(?<=\\s?\\d{4}.?\\s)(", pattern, ")?(?=,)")))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option by removing the bracket surrounding the 4 digit year and then use the OP's pattern without the `()`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(str_replace_all(txt, "\\((\\d{4})\\)", "\\1"),
     str_c("(?<=\\d{4}\\s)(", pattern, ")(?=,)"))[[1]]
#[1] "Mining"           "Computer Science" "J. Data Science"
```

---

Or another option is

```
str_extract_all(txt, str_c("(?<=\\(?\\d{4}\\)?\\s)(", pattern, ")(?=,)"))[[1]]
#[1] "Mining"           "Computer Science" "J. Data Science"
```